# Trying to create mechanism that finds a word in a paragraph and replaces it with another word in javascript

Tags: javascript

I've still learning javascript so apologies if this is an easy question.

i am trying to replace all occurrences of a word in a string with another word, for example if i am wanting to change all occurrences of the word "brown" with "red" in the following string.

I think the my final output of the variable paragraph when logged to the console should be "The quick red fox jumps over the lazy dog"; however I keep getting "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";.

I've tried using the splice() method instead of reassigning tempArray to "newWord" in my for loop but it still didn't work. I'm testing in with chrome developer tools.

Here's my code:

```
/* Creates mechanism that finds a word in a paragraph and replaces it
   with another word */

//Declare the original string
var paragraph = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

//Convert paragraph in individual words
var tempArray = paragraph.split(" "); 

// Introduce the word to be found; to be replaced
var oldWord = "brown";

// Introduces new word to replace old
var newWord = "red";

//Iterate over the array to find and replace the word
for (var i = 0; i <= tempArray.length; i++) {
    if (tempArray[i] === "oldWord") {
        tempArray[i] = "newWord";
    }
}

/* Reconvert the modified array to string by assigning it to the
   original variable */

paragraph = tempArray.join(" ");

// Display your results, it's not an array anymore
console.log(paragraph);
```

Comment: `paragraph.replace("brown", "red");`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript), the best solution to this problem might be using `replace`.

However (and for learning purposes), your code works fine if you make a couple of changes in the `for` statement and the loop body:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {// You have to iterate until tempArray.length - 1
    if (tempArray[i] === oldWord) {// Don't wrap it in ""
        tempArray[i] = newWord;// Don't wrap it in ""
    }
}
```

I will elaborate the comments I put in the code a bit more:

1. In js, strings are wrapped in double quotes or simple quotes. If you wrap the name of a variable in quotes, JS will treat it as a string and not as a variable. Thus the comparation won't be correct.
2. In an array, valid indexes are from 0 to array.length - 1. Accesing an array in position array.length will not throw an error (as in other languages, like Java) but it will return `undefined` (which usually isn't the expected behaviour).

You can check the result of your code in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3nr2jfb/) (opening the console). Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can use replace() function try something like:

```
var result="";
var para="hello hello test word ";
result=para.replace("hello","replaced");
console.log(para);//original values
console.log(result);//modified one
```